# Trouble booting Ubuntu to Sony VAIO

Tags: system-installation

For some reason, my Sony VIAO laptop won't boot Ubuntu.

I tried pressing the F2, F11, F12, and Del Key to see if that will bring up the BIOS, but it didn't work.

I tried going to advanced startup on Windows 8 and tried booting it from my USB Drive (EFI USB DISK :E) which I am assuming it's my since I named the USB drive :E.

When I tried starting up there, it will stay on the VAIO splash screen for a couple minutes, and boot up Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

With the power off, press and **HOLD DOWN** the <kbd>ASSIST</kbd> button, and then power it up. This should give you the BIOS menu, from which you can change the boot order to make it boot from CD.